# create a dictionary and then concatenate the variables according to the id in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, concatenation

I have a Json file with about 3566 lines.
I need to cocatenate the binary variable according to the id.
For example, at the moment I have as many files_id as binary. And it's supposed to be 1:1 , ie have an files_id and a corresponding binary. That is, I have to cocatenate the binaries, in order to have a single binary.

How do you recommend doing this process?
I've already managed to import the file into python:

```
import json 
f = open('1234567.json') 
type(f.read())
print(content[:1999999])
```

[Import Json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aC99.png)

I was thinking of creating a dictionary with the fields: files_id and binary.
But how do I map all files_id and binaries, if I can't see all data in python, due to file size?
Note: the data type is a string

After creating the dictionary, condemned the binary variable. Do I think this is effective?

Comment: consider using `with open('1234567.json', 'r')  as f:`  instead of `f = open('1234567.json')`. If you use the latter, don't forget to call `f.close()` at the end.  In your code you are doing `print(content[:1999999])`  but content is an undefined variable, you haven't read the file at all, just opened it, so if jupyter doesn;t complain it means you have defined content in another cell, so what you have printed is completely unrelated to the file you opened. And what you mean by `condemned the binary variable`? Is condemned a mistranslation?

Comment: @Sembei Norimaki In my dataset I have a variable called binary. The content of this variable is an encoded file. Problem: the binary is split into several lines and I need to concatenate the binary variable into a single line.